# Only One Out of Many Session Variables Dissapear When Loading New Page

Tags: php, session

I built an app to predict admission to business school. I am adding functionality to change the inputs to the calculator without having to start over again. I have two pages update_gmat.php and update_round.php. All of the variable load properly on update_gmat.php but if I am on update_round.php and then change Round again and return to update_round.php, then the Round session variable goes blank. I am able to set the Round session variable and it works on the first load but disappears when I go to the next page. I have about 25 total session variables and Round is the only one that disappears.

Here is update_gmat.php:

```
<?php

require_once "dbconnect2.php";
require_once "functions.php";

session_start();

$EMAIL = $_SESSION["EMAIL"];
$NEW_GMAT = $_POST["newGmat"];
$OLD_GMAT = $_SESSION["GMAT"];
$GPA = $_SESSION["GPA"];
$WORK = $_SESSION["WORK"];
$MAJOR = $_SESSION["MAJOR"];
$INDUSTRY = $_SESSION["INDUSTRY"];
$AGE = $_SESSION["AGE"];
$COUNTRY = $_SESSION["COUNTRY"];
$ROUND = $_SESSION["ROUND"];

$verify_variables =  verifyInputs($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $AGE, $EMAIL, TRUE);
$verify_gmat = verifyGMAT($NEW_GMAT);

if($verify_gmat == "True") {
if($verify_variables == "True") {

    $_SESSION["GMAT"] = $NEW_GMAT;

    $st_row = '<tr style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">';
    $st_cell = '<td style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">';
    $er = '</tr>';
    $ec = '</td>';

    echo '<table style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">
        <tbody style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">';
    echo $st_row . $st_cell . '<center>School</center>' . $ec;
    echo $st_cell . '<center>GMAT: ' . $NEW_GMAT . '</center>' . $ec;
    echo $st_cell . '<center>GMAT: ' . $OLD_GMAT . '</center>' . $ec . $er;

    if($_SESSION["HARVARD"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Harvard");
        echoCell(processHarvard($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processHarvard($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;        
    } 
    if($_SESSION["STANFORD"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Stanford");
        echoCell(processStanford($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processStanford($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["WHARTON"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Wharton");
        echoCell(processWharton($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processWharton($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["BOOTH"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Booth");
        echoCell(processBooth($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processBooth($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["SLOAN"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Sloan");
        echoCell(processSloan($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processSloan($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["KELLOGG"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Kellogg");
        echoCell(processKellogg($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processKellogg($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["HAAS"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Haas");
        echoCell(processHaas($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processHaas($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["COLUMBIA"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Columbia");
        echoCell(processColumbia($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processColumbia($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["TUCK"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Tuck");
        echoCell(processTuck($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processTuck($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["NYU"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("NYU");
        echoCell(processNYU($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processNYU($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["ROSS"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Ross");
        echoCell(processRoss($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processRoss($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["YALE"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Yale");
        echoCell(processYale($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processYale($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["DARDEN"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Darden");
        echoCell(processDarden($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processDarden($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["DUKE"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Duke");
        echoCell(processDuke($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processDuke($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["CORNELL"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Cornell");
        echoCell(processCornell($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processCornell($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["MCCOMBS"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("McCombs");
        echoCell(processDarden($NEW_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echoCell(processDarden($OLD_GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    echo '</tbody>
        </table>';

    echo '<form action="update_gmat.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 15px">Update GMAT:</div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="newGmat" /></div>';
    echo '<input value="Change GMAT" type="submit"><br><br>';
    echo '</form>';

    echo '<form action="update_round.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 15px">Update Application Round:</div>
        <div><select name="newRound">
            <option value="Round 1">Round 1</option>
            <option value="Round 2">Round 2</option>
            <option value="Round 3">Round 3</option>
            <option value="Round 4">Round 4</option>
         </select></div> ';
    echo '<input value="Change Round" type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
}
else
{
    echo "Email: " . $EMAIL . "<br>";
    echo "New GMAT: " . $NEW_GMAT . "<br>";
    echo "Old GMAT: " . $OLD_GMAT . "<br>";
    echo "GPA: " . $GPA . "<br>";
    echo "Work Exp: " . $WORK . "<br>";
    echo "Major: " . $MAJOR . "<br>";
    echo "Industry: " . $INDUSTRY . "<br>";
    echo "Age: " . $AGE . "<br>";
    echo "Country: " . $COUNTRY . "<br>";
    echo "Round: " . $ROUND . "<br>";

}
}
else
{
    echo $verify_gmat;

    echo 'You enterered a GMAT of "' . $NEW_GMAT . '"<br>';

    echo '<form action="update_gmat.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 15px">Enter Legitimate GMAT Score:</div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="newGmat" /></div>';
    echo '<input value="Change GMAT" type="submit"><br><br>';
    echo '</form>';

    echo '<form action="update_round.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 15px">Update Application Round:</div>
        <div><select name="newRound">
            <option value="Round 1">Round 1</option>
            <option value="Round 2">Round 2</option>
            <option value="Round 3">Round 3</option>
            <option value="Round 4">Round 4</option>
         </select></div> ';
    echo '<input value="Change Round" type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
}

echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

I added a bunch of echo statements in update_round.php to see when the session variables have values in them.
Here is update_round.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once "dbconnect2.php";
require_once "functions.php";

echo "Session Round = " . $_SESSION["ROUND"] . "<br>";
echo "Email: " . $_SESSION["EMAIL"] . "<br>";
echo "GMAT: " . $_SESSION["GMAT"] . "<br>";
echo "GPA: " . $_SESSION["GPA"] . "<br>";
echo "Work Exp: " . $_SESSION["WORK"] . "<br>";
echo "Major: " . $_SESSION["MAJOR"] . "<br>";
echo "Industry: " . $_SESSION["INDUSTRY"] . "<br>";
echo "Age: " . $_SESSION["AGE"] . "<br>";
echo "Country: " . $_SESSION["COUNTRY"] . "<br>";

$EMAIL = $_SESSION["EMAIL"];
$GMAT = $_SESSION["GMAT"];
$GPA = $_SESSION["GPA"];
$WORK = $_SESSION["WORK"];
$MAJOR = $_SESSION["MAJOR"];
$INDUSTRY = $_SESSION["INDUSTRY"];
$AGE = $_SESSION["AGE"];
$COUNTRY = $_SESSION["COUNTRY"];
$OLD_ROUND = $_SESSION["ROUND"];
$NEW_ROUND = $_POST["newRound"];

echo "Session Round = " . $_SESSION["ROUND"] . "<br>";
echo "Old Round = " . $OLD_ROUND . "<br>";

$verify_variables =  verifyInputs($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $AGE, $EMAIL, TRUE);


if($verify_variables == "True") {

    echo "Session Round = " . $_SESSION["ROUND"] . "<br>";
    echo "New Round = " . $NEW_ROUND . "<br>";
    $_SESSION["ROUND"] = $NEW_ROUND;
    echo "New Round = " . $NEW_ROUND . "<br>";
    echo "Session Round = " . $_SESSION["ROUND"] . "<br>";

    $st_row = '<tr style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">';
    $st_cell = '<td style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">';
    $er = '</tr>';
    $ec = '</td>';

    echo '<table style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">
        <tbody style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">';
    echo $st_row;
    echo echoCell("School");
    echo echoCell($NEW_ROUND);
    echo echoCell($OLD_ROUND);
    echo $er;

    if($_SESSION["HARVARD"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Harvard");
        echoCell(processHarvard($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processHarvard($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;        
    } 
    if($_SESSION["STANFORD"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Stanford");
        echoCell(processStanford($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processStanford($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["WHARTON"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Wharton");
        echoCell(processWharton($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processWharton($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["BOOTH"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Booth");
        echoCell(processBooth($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processBooth($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["SLOAN"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Sloan");
        echoCell(processSloan($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processSloan($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["KELLOGG"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Kellogg");
        echoCell(processKellogg($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processKellogg($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["HAAS"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Haas");
        echoCell(processHaas($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processHaas($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["COLUMBIA"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Columbia");
        echoCell(processColumbia($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processColumbia($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["TUCK"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Tuck");
        echoCell(processTuck($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processTuck($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["NYU"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("NYU");
        echoCell(processNYU($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processNYU($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["ROSS"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Ross");
        echoCell(processRoss($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processRoss($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["YALE"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Yale");
        echoCell(processYale($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processYale($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["DARDEN"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Darden");
        echoCell(processDarden($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processDarden($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["DUKE"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Duke");
        echoCell(processDuke($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processDuke($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["CORNELL"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("Cornell");
        echoCell(processCornell($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processCornell($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    if($_SESSION["MCCOMBS"]) {
        echo $st_row;
        echoCell("McCombs");
        echoCell(processDarden($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $NEW_ROUND));
        echoCell(processDarden($GMAT, $GPA, $WORK, $MAJOR, $INDUSTRY, $AGE, $COUNTRY, $OLD_ROUND));
        echo $er;
    }
    echo '</tbody>
        </table>';

    echo '<form action="update_gmat.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 15px">Update GMAT:</div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="newGmat" /></div>';
    echo '<input value="Change GMAT" type="submit"><br><br>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '<form action="update_round.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 15px">Update Application Round:</div>
        <div><select name="newRound">
            <option value="Round 1">Round 1</option>
            <option value="Round 2">Round 2</option>
            <option value="Round 3">Round 3</option>
            <option value="Round 4">Round 4</option>
         </select></div> ';
    echo '<input value="Change Round" type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';

    echo "Session Round = " . $_SESSION["ROUND"] . "<br>";    
}
else
{
    echo "Email: " . $EMAIL . "<br>";
    echo "GMAT: " . $GMAT . "<br>";
    echo "GPA: " . $GPA . "<br>";
    echo "Work Exp: " . $WORK . "<br>";
    echo "Major: " . $MAJOR . "<br>";
    echo "Industry: " . $INDUSTRY . "<br>";
    echo "Age: " . $AGE . "<br>";
    echo "Country: " . $COUNTRY . "<br>";
    echo "Round: " . $ROUND . "<br>";
}

echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

When I go from the calculator to update_round.php, it works the first load then the round session variable disappears. When I go from update_gmat.php to update_round.php, it works on the first load then the round session variable disappears. Once the Round session variable stops working, even if I go back to update_gmat.php and come back, it still won't work.

In the original calculator, I set the round from an HTML form post:

```
$_SESSION["ROUND"] = $_POST["inputRound"];
```

Here is the output coming from update_gmat.php to update_round.php:
[image: output 1]

Here is the output starting at update_round.php and returning to update_round.php:
[image: output 2]

I have already Googled the issue with no luck. Any help would be amazing. I'm new to posting on Stack Overflow, so sorry if I didn't submit the question properly. I frequently use old questions for help but this is the first time I have not found someone with a similar question.

Comment: How are you storing session between requests? This is generally a setting configured in your php.ini; for the most part requests in PHP are stateless, meaning you have to pass in the values for variables somehow (like you did with the `$_POST` parameter).

Comment: Just fyi you can use `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see everything in the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: @CourtlandCaldwell I'm fairly new to PHP, so I am using whatever the default session storing is. Am I supposed to do anything special to save session variables? Thanks for the tip on var_dump!

Comment: So I think the issue is that update_round.php isn't actually finding anything in the `"newRound"` post parameter. Try var_dumping the $_POST array at the beginning of your update_round.php

Comment: @CourtlandCaldwell I have added in the var_dump and ROUND is the only session variable that is null. update_round.php is finding the new round value, it just can't find anything in the round session variable to populate $OLD_ROUND.

Comment: I was looking for you to var_dump the `$_POST` (as opposed to `$_SESSION`) variable because you are performing a mutation: `$_SESSION["ROUND"] = $NEW_ROUND;` that depends on `$NEW_ROUND = $_POST["newRound"];`

Comment: @CourtlandCaldwell Thanks for the advice. I never could get it working but and I was wasting too much time. I figured out a workaround using 'get' to send the Round variables. I know its not secure or the most professional way to do it but I was about to smash my computer. I appreciate your effort!